# DAX: Returning information on two (or more) matching items in a single column

Tags: filtering, powerpivot

in PowerPivot, I am struggling to find information on matching values in the same column.

I would like to display the matching name in the below table, e.g. for John with ID '1' it would be Peter (also with ID '1'), for Jack (ID '2') it would be Mary (also ID '2'), etc.

I have been able to 1) find the number of occurrences using:

```
=COUNTX(FILTER (Table2, (EARLIER ( [ID] ) = [ID] )),Table2[Name])
```

...also, I was able to add up the matching values with

```
=SUMX(FILTER (Table2, (EARLIER ( [ID] ) = [ID] )),Table2[Name])
```

...but was unable to display 'Peter' in the row of 'John' and 'John' in the row of Peter. 
I am assuming it is possible, not sure how...any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution (thanks to TomMartens on the Power BI blog), it is CONCATENATEX, working exactly the same as SUMX or COUNTX).

Thanks everyone!